# Prompt for a name and make a table in DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to prompt for a name and then pass the name to a function that will find the given name from the given array with subarrays. I should use the found array element to print out the name in the DOM, the voting status, and the given grade as a table.

For example: [[Jack, true, 10],[John, false],[Rachel, true, 7]]. When user input in prompt is Jack, than in DOM should be printed out: JACK, VOTED, 10 as a table.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: So break it up into parts. We are not here to do homework.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var name = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
for (i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
    if (array[i][0] == name) {
        document.getElementById('myDOM').innerHTML = array[i][0] + ',' + array[i][1] + ',' + array[i][2];
    };
}
```

For 'myInput' and 'myDOM' you will want to fill in the IDs of the elements that you are taking the input from and choosing to output to.